# How the differentiation happens of the expression $\ln t=\ln r + \ln h$

Tags: calculus

when we differentiate the expression  $\ln t=\ln r + \ln h$ it becomes  $(\Delta t)/t=(\Delta r)/r+(\Delta h)/h$ in this what we are differentiating respect to i understand  $y= \log x$ which differentiated with respect to x it becomes  $dy/dx=1/x$ so how above differentiation works

Comment: $\ln(t)=\ln(r)+\ln(h) \Rightarrow dt \cdot \frac{d}{dt}\left(\ln(t)\right) = dr \cdot \frac{d}{dr}\left(\ln(r)\right) + dh \cdot \frac{d}{dh}\left(\ln(h)\right) \Rightarrow \frac{dt}{t} = \frac{dr}{r} + \frac{dh}{h}$

Comment: how plz show in detail